# Terraform plan shows no updates after adding extra value to CIDR_BLOCKS variable for ingress rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I have a rule for a security group that includes the following code.

```
ingress {
  description = "1984 from xymon client"
  from_port   = local.xymon_port
  to_port     = local.xymon_port
  protocol    = local.tcp_proto
 cidr_blocks = var.xymon_clients_cidr
}
```

The variable just contains a number of CIDR ranges coded as

```
“xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24”, “xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24” etc
```

When I add an extra CIDR range to the variable and run Terraform Plan it comes up with

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
The only way I can apply the change is to manually update it on AWS and then run

```
terraform apply -refresh-only
```

Is their a better way I can code this so it will recognise the updates?

Comment: "When I add an extra CIDR range to the variable and run Terraform Plan" means something is wrong with the variable value modification.

Comment: There are some details missing here. But, one possible issue could be that you are running the command in the wrong directory and you maybe haven't saved the changes in the file where variables are defined. Also, if your variable is not of a required type, that might be the issue. This `“xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24”, “xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24”` leads me to believe that you are not defining the variable as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was an ID 10 T error. There was a lifecycle rule and in there was a single line saying

`ignore_changes = [ingress]`

I didn’t originally write this code and I just hadn’t scrolled down far enough to see this bit.

I think this was added in because a terraform plan was always wanting to change this security group even when there were no changes and this was an easy fix. I have now changed the code so the ingress rules are applied by a security_group_rule and not directly in the security group which has allowed me to remove the ignore and get expected behaviour when doing a terraform plan.